# scroll while writing a substitution

Tags: search, command-line

how can I scroll or move around in the code while writing a search or command ?

I want to write a substitution `:s/xxx/yyy` but I forgot what yyy should be and I need to scroll a little bit to find it, but don't want to leave command line either because it took me a while to type xxx

Comment: vim preserves the incomplete command line you were typing, just press `:` then up arrow or ctrl-p

Answer (score 4):

`<C-g>` and `<C-t>` jump to the next and previous match, respectively.

Also, if the mouse is enabled, you can probably use it (opening the command line window first might be necessary: `<C-f>` if already on `:`, `q:` otherwise). Opening the command-line window has some additional benefits, so is worth looking into.

However, if the replacement is difficult to remember, I’d consider this workflow:

1. (Optional: find `yyy` and yank it into a register)
2. `/xxx` until you’re happy with the search pattern
3. `:s//yyy` *or* `:s//<C-r>{reg}` (type <kbd>CTRL-r</kbd> literally, using the register you yanked `yyy` into)